# Which is correct, “needed for next year” or “needed for THE next year”?

Tags: articles, definite-article

1. These are the things needed for next scholastic year.
2. These are the things needed for **the** next scholastic year.

I think the article ‘the’ sounds awkward before ‘next’ because next is not a noun.  Are both sentences, correct?  Do they mean the same?

Comment: Why do you think 'the' has to be next to a noun? Can’t we say “the green car”?

Comment: 'Next year' is the year after _this_ one. 'The next year' is the year after whatever date we are speaking about, maybe in the past or future. "There was a good harvest so they were sure of plenty of food for the next year."

Comment: @ColleenV You're right.  So are they both correct?

Comment: Both are correct and similar colloquial English. There might be a *very slight* difference in connotation, where 1. implies that the next scholastic year is imminent, whereas he use of "the" in 2. *might* leave open the possibility that there could be a gap, e.g., if you were to spend a year out of school working. But I may be reading too much into that.